# wait 5 seconds before scroll down in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

The ads are on the top of my page. I want users to wait 5 seconds before scrolling down the page. How to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to block scrolling for 5 seconds?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily-using-javascript/) it may help. You can easily make this work but be specific. StackOverflow is not for code provide service. You have to try first to find answer and then if not found, post here.